Wrong proof of Inverse function theorem
Is there anything wrong in my attempt to prove the following section of Inverse function theorem by following:
The section I try to prove: Let $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable on $U$ where $0 \in U$, if $Df$ is invertible at 0, then $f$ is locally injective. (ie. there's a dis $B(0,r)$ of positive radius $r$
about 0
such that $x_1,x_2\in B(0,r)$
implies $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$
.)
Then I try to prove it by:
Since $Df(0)$ is invertible, there exists a $c>0$ such that for all $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we get $|Df(0)h|>c|h|$.
Proof:
Consider $S = \{ h \in \mathbb R^n \mid \| h \| = 1 \}$
. Then $S$
is the $n−1$-sphere, and is compact because $n$
is finite. If we define
$$Q(h)=\left \|Df(0)h  \right \|$$
$Q$
is a continuous function on a compact set, hence has some minimum value $c\geq0$ and there's some point $k\in S$
for which $Q(k)=c$
. If c
were zero, this would mean that $Df(0)k=Df(0)0$
, so that multiplication by $Df(0)$
is not injective; hence $c>0$. $\square $
Now let $E(h)=f(h)-f(0)-Df(0)h$ for $h\neq 0$, since $f$ is differentiable at $p$  there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|E(h)|=|f(h)-f(0)-Df(0)h|<c|h|$ for all $0<|h|<\delta$.
So for all $x_1\neq x_2\in B(0,\delta)$,
$$f(x_2)-f(x_1)=Df(0)(x_2-x_1)+E(x_2)-E(x_1)$$
Since $Df(0)(x_2-x_1)>c|x_2-x_1|$ and $E(x_2)-E(x_1)<c|x_2-x_1|$ (inverse triangle inequality?), we get $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|>0$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in B(0,\delta)$ and hence $f$ is locally injective. $\square $
Would be grateful if anyone could point out my mistakes.
Besides, is it possible to prove locally injective implies $f$ is locally bijective (ie. there exists neighbourhoods $N_p$, $N_q$ (where $q=f(p)$) such that $f:N_p \to N_q$ is bijective)?

I'm not sure I see offhand any technical problems - we'll see as I work through it - but there are some presentation issues that really bug me.

What's wrong with my attempt to prove the first part of Inverse function theorem by following:

It'd be helpful if you stated the thing you're trying to prove. There are many many statements of the IVT (e.g., the 1-dimensional one, the manifolds one, ...)

First I reduce the first part of IVT to the Claim: Let $f$ be $R^n\to R^m$. If $Df(0)$ is injective, then locally $f$ is injective.

If you're having trouble knowing whether a proof is correct, it's really useful saying what each assertion means. So "locally $f$ is injective" deserves a gloss, something like this: "i.e., there's a disk D of positive radius $r$ about $0$ such that $x_1, x_2 \in D$ implies $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$."

Then I try to prove it by:


Since $Df(0)$ is invertible, there exists a $c>0$ such that $|Df(0)h|>c|h|$ ($Df$ is finite-dimensional),

See? Right there is a place where laying out your hypotheses would help. Also, what's $h$? (Sure, it's an arbitrary vector in the tangent space to $\mathbb R^n$ at $0$, which you've identified with $\mathbb R^n$.) Let's try a rewrite:
"Because $n$ is finite and $Df(0)$ is invertible...." Oh...wait! That's not true! What we know is that it's injective; but injective only means invertible if $n = m$. It turns out you've mis-stated the theorem. Oops. Let's pretend that $m$ is just a typo for $n$ in your statement and continue. "Because $n$ is finite and $Df(0)$ is an injective linear map from $n$-space to $n$-space, it's also invertible. So..." Wait a minute...your next assertion doesn't seem all that clear from invertibility. Let's try something different:
"Consider $S = \{ h \in \mathbb R^n \mid \| h \| = 1 \}$. Then $S$ is the $n-1$-sphere, and is compact because $n$ is finite. If we define
$$
Q(h) = {\|Df(0)h\|}
$$
then $Q$ is a continuous function on a compact set, hence has some minimum value $c \ge 0$. And because $Q$ is continuous and $S$ is compact, there's some point $k \in S$ for which $Q(k) = c$. If $c$ were zero, this would mean that $Df(0)k = Df(0)0$, so that multiplication by $Df(0)$ is not injective; hence $c > 0$."
We continue

so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|E(h)|=|f(h)-f(0)-Df(0)h|<c|h|$ for all $|h|<\delta$.

That seems like a big leap. Let's check it out. Let's look at the example $f: \mathbb R^1 \to \mathbb R^1 : x \mapsto x$. The derivative at $0$ is exactly $1$, and multiplication by 1 is indeed injective on the real line. Your assertion about $c$ holds for $c = 0.5$, so let's run with that. Now you're claiming that for every (small enough) real number $h$,
$$
|E(h)| = |f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) h | < c|h|.
$$
There's the slight problem that you didn't actually define $E$, but let's assume you meant to say
"Let
$$
E(h) = f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) h."
$$
Fine. Then the equation above reads:
\begin{align}
|E(h)| &= |f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) h | < c|h|.
\end{align}
Let's go ahead and substitute in the data from our $f(x) = x$ example. That gives...
\begin{align}
|E(h)| 
&= |f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) h | < c|h| \\
&= |h - 0 - 1 \cdot h | < c|h| \\
&= |0 | < c|h| \\
&= 0  < c|h|.
\end{align}
When we plug in $h = 0$ (which is certainly a vector whose length is less than $\delta$), we get $0 < 0$, which is nonsense.
This seems to me like a good place to stop and let you go back and try rewriting your proof.
Suggestions: Name everything before you use it. Assert what you're proving before offering a proof. Proofread. Write a statement-reason two-column proof if necessary to clarify your ideas. Then maybe it'll be worth another shot.

Thanks for your advice! I have rewritten my proof following your advice. (I mistyped Df to be injective instead of invertible in hypothesis)
